# Is it considered bad practice to set height and width using a fixed number in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently developing in React Native.

Given the variety of screen sizes across mobile devices, is it bad practice to use something like:

```
width: 50, height: 50
```

Is there a better way to set the height and width of components within Views? Specifically `TextInput`, `Buttons` and `FlatList` components.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what element it is you are setting the size for. If you require things like badges or icons to be a set size, then being explicit is fine.

If you are looking at implementing things that need to respond dynamically (ie buttons as wide as the screen), definitely rely more on flex, padding and margins to guide the elements width and/or height.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered a bad practice in the sense that you are creating a static page, instead of responsive.
Certain components should be fixed, such as a picture, a banner...
And some elements should be allocated dynamically, or responsively with percentages or using flex.